# Determine I through load resistor in circuit with diodes in series

Tags: diodes

I'm trying to find an expression for the current through the resistor \$R\$ when the AC-source is at max voltage of 5 volts.

\$U_T\$ represents the voltage drop across each diode.

\$R_D\$ represents the the internal resistance of each diode.

As you can see on the picture, I'm wondering how the expression for the current \$I\$ through the resistor is derived?

Now I got the wrong answer if I said that after all the voltage drops the voltage is zero, therefore I'm trying to understand how the formula on the picture has been derived.

[image: 2 diodes in serires with a resistor]

Comment: What are the circles between the diodes and \$R_D\$'s?

Comment: Why do you say that it's missing? It's right there on the bottom.

Comment: They represent the voltage drops across the each diode. Why they are positive baffles me. Sry see the U and R for for R, edited initial question.

Comment: (removed comment on what is a convention) When you compute the current in a loop you account for all generators in the loop (Um and the two Ut's) and not for voltage drops on resistors. The resistors are accounted for in  the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rearrange your formula, you get
$$
(U_m - 2U_T) = I_m (2R_d + R)
$$
which looks like
$$
V = IR
$$
where \$R\$ is the sum of all of the resistors in the loop and \$V\$ is the voltage across that summed resistor.

Kirchoff tells you that the voltage across this resistor is the same as the voltage looking at the rest of the circuit, which is \$U_m - 2U_T\$, because there must be a voltage drop across each of the diodes for current to flow.

Comment: ohm's law, I see it now, thx.